# Excel - highlight cells if a percentage of the text is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a single column spreadsheet with thousands of rows of business names.

There are many, many duplicates which are easy enough to find and purge. However are even more partial matches. For example, there is a law firm that I have seen listed multiple ways -

Jones, Smith and Paul

Jones, Smith, and Paul

Jones, Smith & Paul

Jones, Smith & Paul, LLC

Jones, Smith, Johnson & Paul, LLC

There are so many variations in these business names. The idea I keep coming back to is creating a formula to highlight cells than contain X% of same text/characters. That way, I could make a few passes, say one pass with 50% matching text, 75% matching text, etc.

I have been scouring the google and while I come across many posts asking similar things, I haven't come across anything that will solve this for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future, Microsoft made an Excel plugin called Fuzzy Lookup that accomplishes exactly this partial/percentage based matching.

Comment: It's great to see you have found a solution. Can you show us how you made it work? That might be interesting to see for others, having similar problems.

Comment: Sure @Dominique. The Fuzzy Lookup plugin has to pointed at tables. So if your data is unstructured like mine was, create a table. I don't know if it's necessary but I created a copy of the table on a second sheet. Then on a third sheet, open up the plugin, select your two tables (automatically detected) and tell it what 'similarity score' you want. This is a slider from 0 to 1. Click run and it will automatically list all its detected quasi-duplicates on that 3rd sheet. From my (limited) experience, anything below 0.75 results in poor matching.